# Oracle Apex how to load data from different table but save it to another table?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, sql-insert, insert-update, tabular-form

i've been using apex and i understand how it updates and saves records normally.

For this case, i would need to load from a table but save it to another table upon submit button.

I'm aware that it would be easy like forms where i could do a manual insert process.
im doing it in tabular forms and i dont really know how to manipulate this process.

suppose that i'm loading a set of questionnaires on the tabular form and have a yes/no selection.

so the questions would come from table A and i would need to save it to table B.

in this case i cant just set default value for the each row of tabular for the questions coz it would be dynamic and this example is on a small scale. i would need it to load from **table A** and save to **table B**.

could anyone guide me on doing this or provide any tutorials of some sort?

Comment: After the user selects yes/no and clicks save, do you want it to UPDATE the answers table, or INSERT into the answers table?

Answer (score 0):

add a field lets say option field to table A, which will save the yes/no.
Then on table A itself, you have a after insert trigger,
then you validate if the option field is 'yes', insert into table b.

from this, you'll have a log also of all the records uploaded on table a.